# How to make two active dialogs in the same time in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I'm trying to run two windows in MFC in the same time - when i run my app.
In BOOL CrTestTaskApp::InitInstance() - init function of my app i wrote this:

```
CrStartDlg sDlg;
sDlg.DoModal();
CrMainDlg dlg;
m_pMainWnd = &dlg;
INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();

if (nResponse == IDOK)
{

}
else if (nResponse == IDCANCEL)
{

}
```

But second dialog apears only after i closed first. And also, if i make Modal() second dialog on BtnClick() first dialog - i cant switch between them.. Active only one...

Help me pls.

Comment: You cannot have 2 Modal dialogs open at the same time.  If you want to have more than 1 dialog open, you have to use Modeless dialogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need modeless dialogs, as opposed to modal created by `DoModal` method.

Modeless dialogs are created with [`CDialog::Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhth57kd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and act as regular windows, responding to messages dispatched via shared message queue/pump.

- [Creating a Modeless Dialog Box with MFC Libraries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103788)
- [C++ Starting several modeless dialogs using WINAPI ( no MFC )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280781/c-starting-several-modeless-dialogs-using-winapi-no-mfc)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me. Could you please tell if I could make already existing dialog modelless?

Comment: You might needs some minor updates there, esp. around `EndDialog` calls which are not applicable to modeless dialogs. Most of message handlers should be fine.